# Confusion with click/hover behavior on iOS with jQuery

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, ipad, hover

I have a webpage with jQuery. When I open it in iPad / iPhone, hyperlinks do not work as expected when setting hover behavior for it.

I have tried to figure this out by browsing many websites over internet but could not find any particular solution. Maybe I'm unable to understand what is happening. I would appreciate some clues and solution.

Here is the code that sets hover:

```
.box:hover .box_details .description2 {
  height: auto !important;
  display: block
}

.box .social {
  width: 150px ;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99 ;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: 50%;
  left: -75px;
  text-align: center
}

.box:hover .social ul {
  margin-top: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: margin-top linear 0.5s ;
  transition: margin-top linear 0.5s ;
}

.box .social ul {
  width: 100% ;
  float: left ;
  margin-top: -50px ;
}

.box .social ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1% 1% 0 1%;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 22%
}

.box .social ul li img {
  width: 100% !important;
  position: relative
}
```

Please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us your code? also... how can you hover in a touch screen device? either you touch it or not, there is no mouse cursor to hover on elements...

Comment: What's 'hover' in iOS anyway?

Comment: You may do better with [jQuery Mobile Events](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/), try `tap` or `taphold`.

Comment: .box:hover .box_details .description2 { height:auto !important; display:block}

.box  .social { width:150px ; position:absolute; z-index:99 ; margin: 0 auto;  margin-left:50%; left: -75px; text-align:center}
 .box:hover .social ul{ margin-top:10px; -webkit-transition:margin-top linear 0.5s ; transition:margin-top linear 0.5s ; }
.box  .social  ul { width:100% ; float:left ; margin-top:-50px ; }
.box  .social ul li { float:left; list-style:none; margin:1% 1% 0 1%; line-height:20px; width:22% }
.box  .social ul li img{ width:100% !important; position:relative}

Comment: i can not edit the j query as it comes from other website.

Comment: please add some code for better understanding

Comment: Lol, is the iOS screen meant to guess where your finger is hovering to detect a hover event? Think about your question, really, just think about it for a moment and you might get an idea why you have some down votes :)

Comment: Well, I think that when you use hover, on first tap that hover is activated, and on the second tap actual click is activated on iOS's UIWebView. So I find the question genuine, and have rephrased it for better explanation as the person who wrote question has personally asked me to look into this page.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about jQuery event both desktop and mobile

```
$('.selector').on('mouseenter touchstart', function(){ 
     // Do something
});

$('.selector').on('mouseleave touchend', function(){
     // Dhing someto
});
```

Comment: This is not equivalent to .hover(). A touch-enabled menu requires a touchstart followed by a touchend that will keep the menu open. Then, it needs to close when you tap again, which will generates another touchstart and touchend.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change hover events to touch events.

Comment: how to change hover to touch event for i phone and i pad

Comment: if you use jQuery, it would be like: 

`$(element).on('touchstart',function(){     //your code }).on('touchend',function(){  //your code})`

Comment: @zqillyc - not exactly. That method would only work while your finger is touching.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS all hover events are treated as a click event. So, if you have a :hover style on a link, a user will have to click the link twice.
Here is an article that talks about the iOS :hover/[double tap issue](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/07/05/ios-has-a-hover-problem/) .

Answer (score 0):

Any site for mobile (used in Iphone or Ipad or any device) the ***hover effect is unnecessary*** (due to touch) and it won't have effect.

Better go only with [**`:active`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aactive) psuedoclass.